# flex - Methods of creating pivot or tabular reports?

Tags: apache-flex, mongodb, reporting, flash-builder

Looking for some ideas, strategies, tools, etc. on creating reports from Flash Builder / Flex 4.

I have a flex application that allows create/read/update/delete of client information from a back-end database.  It uses web services (zend amf -> mongo db or mysql).  I already have the client data IN flex via the web service as a collection for example.

A user requests the ability to generate a report - to display a list of clients under a certain age in a tabular excel style grid (datagrid most likely).   It will be sorted and subtotaled by a demographic such as "insurance type".  Ideally the user would like to be able to select the insurance types allowed on the report (or in the datagrid/pivot table).

I know one option would be to present the user with a series of check boxes or a multi-select list to choose the insurance types.   Then, present them with a data grid or advanced data grid component to display the 'report'.

What other techniques, options or components are available / have people used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought I would post this as an answer and hopefully people can contribute additional solutions:

Reporting solutions I have found so far:

- OLAP Data Grid component (http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=olapdatagrid_2.html) - whats the advantage of this over the advanced data grid?
- MecGrid (http://www.mechansp.com/prod_mecgrid.php) looks free?
- flexreport (http://code.google.com/p/flexreport/) open source (will it do pivot?)
- daoflex  obsolete flex 2, but generated flex apps based on java code
- Commercial options - I have seen a few different commercial options for data grid components with pivot capability, but I am hoping for a free or built in solution
  To mention them,

  - www.flexmonster.com makes a pivot table component
  - www.flexicious.com - an advanced data grid / pivot table style component
  - FlexBI, ClearBI, Clear Toolkit, Super Grid and others from Farata Systems  (http://sourceforge.net/projects/cleartoolkit/) looks like it was open source at one point and maybe some of it still is, but some of it looks commercial

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to avoid the fact that you're going to have to do some work on your own.  Your solution will be way too custom for a commercial options since only you know the data to display.

You need to create some kind of interface that the user can say what he wants in the report, while Flex queries the services, gets the data it needs to display and knows how to display it properly.  You need to figure out each part for this to work.

Comment: I know any solution is going to require work.   I am used to other database/development environments having built in or templates for building query editors, reporting tools that let the user (or developer) pick and choose fields for output, etc.  I believe the OLAP and other options I listed above (after you posted this I think) help, but I was hoping to hear about some other options for report generation in flex.

Comment: This is a UI SDK, not a database SDK.  Query editors are meant for backend development and the front end should never have direct access to the database, or have a way to run queries directly because it's a major security issue.

Comment: Agree, but I am asking about a front end reporting solution- I never specified I want to give the user direct access or access to ALL the fields. Microsoft Access for example has a simple wizards that let me generate report output (forms/screens) & queries. Then I can tweak the code/UI.  There are other environments that have similar concepts. I just thought a product this mature and I am sure used as a front end UI for a data driven application would have some tools to make data output easier. In fact, I have found some components as I listed in my original post. Hoping to find more options.

Comment: Again, this is a UI SDK **NOT** a database reporting tool.  It can be made into it, but it's kind of hard to create a solution that would encompass the front-end, back-end and database product all in one for it to work.  All of this would need to be custom to your specific architecture.  If you really want to, you could always use [assql](http://code.google.com/p/assql/) to connect to your DB and create a UI to do queries and get the data, but this is crazy insecure and should only be used locally.

Comment: I think we are still not on the same page - assql appears to be a way to allow flex to talk directly to a mysql database.   I already have a connection to the database (via zend afm), so that's not what I need.   I have all the required data IN flex already.   I need to present the data to the user via the "UI".   Anyway, I posted my own answer to clarify what kind of components/tools I am looking for.

Comment: ...since when is a grid a report? *sigh*

Answer (score 0):

have a look at the samples here too:

http://www.adobe.com/devnet-apps/flex/tourdeflex/web/

Select data visualization, and then Select pivot tables and charts, under the Flex Monster folder.

There is a wealth of information and samples there.

One sample:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
        import mx.containers.TitleWindow;
        import mx.controls.Alert;
        import mx.core.FlexGlobals;
        import mx.events.CloseEvent;
        import mx.managers.PopUpManager;
        import mx.utils.ObjectUtil;

        private function get swfFilePath():String {
            // Flex 4
            return (FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.parameters['swfFilePath'] == null) ? 'flexmonster/' : FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.parameters['swfFilePath']; 
            // Flex 3
```

//                return (Application.application.parameters['swfFilePath'] == null) ? 'flexmonster/' : Application.application.parameters['swfFilePath'];
            }

```
         private function addStructure():void {
            apiPivot.addDimension("[Geography]", "Geography");
            apiPivot.addDimension("[Product]", "Product");
            apiPivot.addHierarchy("[Geography]", "[Geography].[Country]", "Country");
            apiPivot.addHierarchy("[Product]", "[Product].[Color]", "Color");
            apiPivot.addHierarchy("[Product]", "[Product].[Category]", "Category");
            apiPivot.addMeasure("[Measures].[Price]", "Price");
            apiPivot.addMeasure("[Measures].[Discount]", "Discount", AggregationName.COUNT);                
        }

        private function addData():void {
            this.clearData();
            this.addStructure();

            var dataRecord:Object = {"[Geography].[Country]": "Australia", "[Product].[Color]": "red", "[Product].[Category]": "Car", "[Measures].[Price]": 123, "[Measures].[Discount]": 10};
            apiPivot.addDataRecord(dataRecord);
            var dataRecord1:Object = {"[Geography].[Country]": "Australia", "[Product].[Color]": "red", "[Product].[Category]": "Book", "[Measures].[Price]": 34.32, "[Measures].[Discount]": 28};
            apiPivot.addDataRecord(dataRecord1);
            var dataRecord2:Object = {"[Geography].[Country]": "Australia", "[Product].[Color]": "blue", "[Product].[Category]": "Book", "[Measures].[Price]": 19.20, "[Measures].[Discount]": 16};
            apiPivot.addDataRecord(dataRecord2);
            var dataRecord3:Object = {"[Geography].[Country]": "Canada", "[Product].[Color]": "green", "[Product].[Category]": "Byke", "[Measures].[Price]": 19.45, "[Measures].[Discount]": 46};
            apiPivot.addDataRecord(dataRecord3);
            var dataRecord4:Object = {"[Geography].[Country]": "Canada", "[Product].[Color]": "red", "[Product].[Category]": "Byke", "[Measures].[Price]": 78.45, "[Measures].[Discount]": 12};
            apiPivot.addDataRecord(dataRecord4);
            var dataRecord5:Object = {"[Geography].[Country]": "Canada", "[Product].[Color]": "red", "[Product].[Category]": "Book", "[Measures].[Price]": 87.45, "[Measures].[Discount]": 9};
            apiPivot.addDataRecord(dataRecord5);
            var dataRecord6:Object = {"[Geography].[Country]": "France", "[Product].[Color]": "white", "[Product].[Category]": "Byke", "[Measures].[Price]": 8.45, "[Measures].[Discount]": 34};
            apiPivot.addDataRecord(dataRecord6);
            var dataRecord7:Object = {"[Geography].[Country]": "France", "[Product].[Color]": "white", "[Product].[Category]": "Byke", "[Measures].[Price]": 85, "[Measures].[Discount]": 2};
            apiPivot.addDataRecord(dataRecord7);
            var dataRecord8:Object = {"[Geography].[Country]": "Canada", "[Product].[Color]": "white", "[Product].[Category]": "Byke", "[Measures].[Price]": 9.45, "[Measures].[Discount]": 6};
            apiPivot.addDataRecord(dataRecord8);
            var dataRecord9:Object = {"[Geography].[Country]": "Canada", "[Product].[Color]": "blue", "[Product].[Category]": "Byke", "[Measures].[Price]": 7.43, "[Measures].[Discount]": 21};
            apiPivot.addDataRecord(dataRecord9);

            var rows:Array = [{"uniqueName": "[Product].[Color]", "sort": "asc", "filter": {"type": "top", "quantity": 3, "measure": "[Measures].[Price]"}}, {"uniqueName": "[Product].[Category]", "sort": "asc"}];
            var columns:Array = [{"uniqueName": "[Geography].[Country]", "sort": "desc", "filter": [{"uniqueName": "[Geography].[Country].[Canada]"}, {"uniqueName": "[Geography].[Country].[Australia]"}]}];
            var pages:Array = [{"uniqueName": "[Product].[Category]"}];
            var measures:Array = [{"uniqueName": "[Measures].[Price]", "aggregation" : "Sum"}, {"uniqueName": "[Measures].[Discount]", "aggregation" : "Count"}];
            var report:ReportValueObject = new ReportValueObject(rows, columns, pages, measures);            
            apiPivot.currencySymbol = "$";
            apiPivot.report = report;
            apiPivot.load();
        }

        private function addStructure1():void {
            apiPivot.addDimension("[谷歌搜索]", "谷歌搜索");
            apiPivot.addDimension("[轻松购物]", "轻松购物");
            apiPivot.addHierarchy("[谷歌搜索]", "[谷歌搜索].[安踏鞋]", "安踏鞋");
            apiPivot.addHierarchy("[轻松购物]", "[轻松购物].[短裤]", "短裤");
            apiPivot.addHierarchy("[轻松购物]", "[轻松购物].[上网本]", "上网本");
            apiPivot.addMeasure("[Measures].[音箱]", "音箱");
            apiPivot.addMeasure("[Measures].[内裤]", "内裤", AggregationName.COUNT);                
        }

        private function addData1():void {
            this.clearData();
            this.addStructure1();
            var array:Array = [
                    ["松购", "踏鞋", "谷歌", 89, 34],
                    ["松购", "音", "浴缸", 77, 83],
                    ["搜索", "踏鞋", "谷歌", 78, 67],
                    ["松购", "踏鞋", "浴缸", 3, 90],
                    ["搜索", "音", "谷歌", 33, 54],
                    ["网本", "内", "帮助", 122, 6]
                ];
            apiPivot.addDataArray(array);

            var rows:Array = [{"uniqueName": "[谷歌搜索].[安踏鞋]", "sort": "asc"}, {"uniqueName": "[轻松购物].[短裤]", "sort": "asc"}];
            var columns:Array = [{"uniqueName": "[轻松购物].[上网本]", "sort": "desc"}];
            var pages:Array = [];
            var measures:Array = [{"uniqueName": "[Measures].[内裤]", "aggregation" : "Sum"}, {"uniqueName": "[Measures].[音箱]", "aggregation" : "Count"}];
            var report:ReportValueObject = new ReportValueObject(rows, columns, pages, measures);
            report.viewType = ViewType.CHARTS;
            report.chartType = ChartType.LINE;
            apiPivot.report = report;
            apiPivot.load();
        } 

        private function getLabels():void {
            var labels:Array = [];
            var strings:Array = [];
            for (var i:int = 0; i < apiPivot.gridRowCount; i++) {
                labels[i] = [];
                for (var j:int = 0; j < apiPivot.gridColumnCount; j++) {
                    var cell:PivotGridCellRenderer = apiPivot.getCell(i,j);
                    labels[i][j] = cell.label;
                }
                strings.push(labels[i].join(", "));
            }
            Alert.show(strings.join("\n"));
        }

        private function clearData():void {
            apiPivot.clear();
        } 

         private function onReady():void {
            this.btnClearData.enabled = true;
            this.btnAddData.enabled = true;
            this.btnAddData1.enabled = true;
            this.addData();
        } 

        private function addPopUp():void {
            var pivot:FlexPivotComponent = new FlexPivotComponent();
            pivot.percentWidth = 100;
            pivot.percentHeight = 100;
            pivot.swfFilePath = this.swfFilePath;
            pivot.configUrl = this.swfFilePath + "simple.xml";

             var window:TitleWindow = new TitleWindow();
            window.title = "Pivot Table"; 
            window.width = 720;
            window.height = 480;
            window.showCloseButton = true;
            window.addEventListener(CloseEvent.CLOSE, function():void {PopUpManager.removePopUp(window)});
            PopUpManager.addPopUp(window, this);
            PopUpManager.centerPopUp(window);

            window.validateNow();
            window.addChild(pivot);
        }

        private function onGridClick(event:Event):void {
            var cell:PivotGridCellRenderer = (event as CellClickEvent).cell;
            var rows:Array = [];
            for (var i:int = 0; i < cell.rows.length; i++) {
                var row:Object = cell.rows[i];
                rows.push(row.hierarchyCaption + "=" + row.caption);
            }
            var rowStr:String = rows.join(", ");

            var columns:Array = [];
            for (i = 0; i < cell.columns.length; i++) {
                var column:Object = cell.columns[i];
                columns.push(column.hierarchyCaption + "=" + column.caption);
            }
            var columnStr:String = columns.join(", ");

            Alert.show("Rows: " + rowStr + "\nColumns: " + columnStr + "\nValue:" + cell.label);
        }

        private function exportRawCSV():void {
            pivot4.export(ExportType.CSV, null, onExportRawCSV);
        }

        private function onExportRawCSV(data:String):void {
            Alert.show(data);
        }

        private function exportFileCSV():void {
            pivot4.export(ExportType.CSV);
        }

    ]]>
</mx:Script>

<mx:Button label="Add Pivot as Popup" click="addPopUp()" horizontalCenter="0" top="4"/>

<mx:Accordion width="100%" height="100%" top="30">
    <mx:Canvas label="Simple Grid" width="100%" height="100%">
        <pivot:FlexPivotComponent width="100%" height="100%" 
              configUrl="{this.swfFilePath}simple.xml" 
              swfFilePath="{this.swfFilePath}"/>
    </mx:Canvas>
    <mx:Canvas label="Pivot Chart" width="100%" height="100%">
        <pivot:FlexPivotComponent width="100%" height="100%"
            styleSheetName="styles/skin.css"
            filename="http://www.flexmonster.com/flash/2010-APR-21/data/data.csv"
            rows="[Color].[Color]"
            columns="[Country].[Country], [Business Type].[Business Type]"
            measures="[Measures].[Price], [Measures].[Quantity]"
            viewType="{ViewType.CHARTS}"
            swfFilePath="{this.swfFilePath}"/>
    </mx:Canvas>
    <mx:Canvas label="MS OLAP sample" width="100%" height="100%">
        <mx:Button label="Fields List" right="5" top="5" selected="true" click="pivot1.openFieldsList()"/>
        <pivot:FlexPivotComponent id="pivot1" width="100%" height="100%" top="30"
            styleSheetName="styles/skin.css"
            showFieldsList="true"
            proxyUrl="http://olap.flexmonster.com/olap/msmdpump.dll"
            dataSourceInfo="Provider=MSOLAP; Data Source=extranet;"
            catalog="Adventure Works DW Standard Edition"
            cube="Adventure Works"
            rows="[Product].[Product Categories],[Measures]"
            columns="[Product].[Style], [Product].[Color]"
            measures="[Measures].[Reseller Order Quantity], [Measures].[Discount Amount]"
            swfFilePath="{this.swfFilePath}"/>
    </mx:Canvas>
    <mx:Canvas label="Mondrian Sample" width="100%" height="100%">
        <mx:Button label="Fields List" right="5" top="5" selected="true" click="pivot2.openFieldsList()"/>
        <pivot:FlexPivotComponent id="pivot2" width="100%" height="100%" top="30"
            styleSheetName="styles/skin.css"
            showFieldsList="true"
            proxyUrl="http://olap.flexmonster.com:8080/mondrian/xmla"
            dataSourceInfo="Provider=Mondrian;DataSource=MondrianFoodMart;"
            catalog="FoodMart"
            cube="Sales"
            rows="{[{uniqueName: '[Education Level]', sort: 'desc'}, {uniqueName: '[Promotion Media]'}]}"
            columns="{[{uniqueName: '[Gender]'}]}"
            measures="{[{uniqueName: '[Measures].[Sales Count]'}, {uniqueName: '[Measures].[Profit]'}]}"
            swfFilePath="{this.swfFilePath}"/>
    </mx:Canvas>
    <mx:Canvas label="Switch View" width="100%" height="100%">
        <mx:Button x="10" y="10" label="Grid" icon="@Embed(source='images/Table.png')" width="100" height="80" color="#0000FF" click="pivot3.showGrid()"/>
        <mx:Button x="115" y="10" label="Bar" icon="@Embed(source='images/Bar Chart.png')" width="100" height="80" color="#0000FF" click="pivot3.showCharts(ChartType.BAR)"/>
        <mx:Button x="220" y="10" label="Line" icon="@Embed(source='images/Line Chart.png')" width="100" height="80" color="#0000FF" click="pivot3.showCharts(ChartType.LINE)"/>
        <mx:Button x="325" y="10" label="Pie" icon="@Embed(source='images/Pie Chart.png')" width="100" height="80" color="#0000FF" click="pivot3.showCharts(ChartType.PIE)"/>
        <mx:Button label="Fields List" right="5" top="5" selected="true" click="pivot3.openFieldsList()"/>
        <pivot:FlexPivotComponent id="pivot3" width="100%" height="100%" top="100" x="10" 
            configUrl="{this.swfFilePath}simple.xml"
            swfFilePath="{this.swfFilePath}"/>
    </mx:Canvas>
    <mx:Canvas label="Print and Export" width="100%" height="100%">
        <mx:Button x="10" y="10" label="HTML" icon="@Embed(source='images/file_htm.png')" width="100" height="80" color="#0000FF" click="pivot4.export(ExportType.HTML, new ExportOptions('styles/misc/export.html'))"/>
        <mx:Button x="115" y="10" label="Raw CSV" icon="@Embed(source='images/file_csv.png')" width="100" height="80" color="#0000FF" click="exportRawCSV()"/>
        <mx:Button x="220" y="10" label="CSV to file" icon="@Embed(source='images/file_csv.png')" width="100" height="80" color="#0000FF" click="exportFileCSV()"/>
        <mx:Button x="325" y="10" label="Image" icon="@Embed(source='images/file_png.png')" width="100" height="80" color="#0000FF" click="pivot4.export(ExportType.IMAGE)"/>
        <mx:Button x="430" y="10" label="PDF" icon="@Embed(source='images/file_pdf.png')" width="100" height="80" color="#0000FF" click="pivot4.export(ExportType.PDF)"/>
        <mx:Button x="535" y="10" label="Print" icon="@Embed(source='images/printer.png')" width="100" height="80" color="#0000FF" click="pivot4.print()"/>
        <mx:Button x="640" y="10" label="Save Report" icon="@Embed(source='images/file_save.png')" width="130" height="80" color="#0000FF" click="pivot4.saveReport('http://localhost/flex_demos/save.php', 'report.xml', function():void {Alert.show('Report was saved!')})"/>
        <pivot:FlexPivotComponent id="pivot4" width="100%" height="100%" top="100" x="10" 
                                  configUrl="{this.swfFilePath}simple.xml" 
                                  swfFilePath="{this.swfFilePath}"/>
    </mx:Canvas>
    <mx:Canvas label="Loading data via API" width="100%" height="100%">
        <mx:Button id="btnClearData" label="Clear Data" enabled="false" x="10" y="5" click="clearData()"/>

        <mx:Button id="btnAddData" label="Add Data" enabled="false" x="110" y="5" click="addData()"/>
        <mx:Button id="btnAddData1" label="Add Data 1" enabled="false" x="210" y="5" click="addData1()"/>
        <pivot:FlexPivotComponent 
            id="apiPivot" top="30" bottom="5" left="0" right="0" autoLoad="false"
            styleSheetName="styles/cherry.css" 
            swfFilePath="{this.swfFilePath}"
            pivotCreationComplete="onReady()"
            gridMouseClick="onGridClick(event)"/>
    </mx:Canvas>
    <mx:Canvas label="中文 / Chinese language" width="100%" height="100%">
        <pivot:FlexPivotComponent width="100%" height="100%" 
                                  configUrl="{this.swfFilePath}chinese.xml" 
                                  swfFilePath="{this.swfFilePath}"/>
    </mx:Canvas>
</mx:Accordion>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a pure javascript solution at [webpivottable](http://webpivottable.com) . No flex, no plugin, no any back end technology dependence. Here is  [demo](http://webpivottable.com/demo) .